# Mulesoft - Can the IMAP connector be used on cloudhub

Tags: email, imap, cloudhub, anypoint-studio

I've created a Mulesoft project using the IMAP connector to retrieve e-mail messages. It works fine running locally via Anypoint Studio.  When I attempt to deploy it to cloudhub, I get the following error:

```
 Your application has failed with exception com.mulesoft.mmc.agent.v3.dto.DeploymentException: Failed to start inbound endpoint "endpoint.imaps.jwu.platform.gmail.com"
```

I understand the limitations with inbound connections to cloudhub.  My question is this, Is there a way to make use of the IMAP connector on cloudhub?  Or am I better off switching over to the POP connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes IMAP connector can be used in the cloudhub.

The IMAP Connector, which is configurable only as an inbound endpoint (also known as a message source) with a one-way exchange pattern, implements a transport channel that enables your Mule application to retrieve email from an IMAP email server.

IMAP is similar to POP3, except IMAP supports both online and offline modes. For instance, IMAP users can leave email messages on the IMAP server until they explicitly delete them. Like POP3, IMAP cannot send email; for that, you must implement an SMTP outbound endpoint.

For a secure transport channel (either TLS or SSL), you can specify the IMAPS protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this flow I have deployed successfully in cloudhub

```
<imaps:connector name="IMAP" validateConnections="true" checkFrequency="1" doc:name="IMAP" deleteReadMessages="false">
        <imaps:tls-client path="*" storePassword="*"/>
        <imaps:tls-trust-store path="*" storePassword="*"/>
    </imaps:connector>
    <flow name="imapFlow">
        <imaps:inbound-endpoint host="imap.gmail.com" port="993" user="example%40gmail.com" password="password" connector-ref="IMAP" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="IMAP"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```